# editing $_POST by using reference

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through `$_POST` values and do some check/validation etc on it as follow :

```
class Input
{
    public function &Clean(&$source, $field = null)
    {
        $toClean = is_array($source) ? empty($field) ? $source : $source[$field] : $source;


        //check if we are going to clean the whole array or only a specific field!
        if (is_array($toClean)) {
            //we foreach every key/field
            foreach ($toClean as $to => $value)
                $toClean[$to] = $this->DoClean($value);
        } else {
            $this->DoClean($toClean);
        }

        return $toClean;
    }

    private function DoClean(&$toClean)
    {
        return strip_tags(trim($toClean));

        }
    }

new Input()->Clean($_POST);
```

but that is not working the actual values of `$_POST` didn't change , what am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to slightly misunderstand the [concept of reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), or at least how to use it. From the PHP doc (emphasis mine) :

> You can pass a variable by reference to a function so **the function can modify the variable**

**You still have to modify the variable inside the function.** And you need not return it anymore, since it is modified.

The easiest example is your `DoClean` method. As you write it, the reference is useless, because you never modify the input value. So the following is strictly equivalent (in terms of what it does) to your function :

```php
private function DoClean($toClean)
{
    return strip_tags(trim($toClean));
}
// use it as follows :
$toClean = $this->DoClean($toClean);
```

However, if you do want to use a reference, the you can modify the input variable. Thus you don't need to return the value anymore, the value you passed to the function will contain the result after the call. For example :

```php
private function DoClean(&$toClean)
{
    $toClean = strip_tags(trim($toClean));
}
// use it as follows
$this->DoClean($toClean);
```

This effect on `$toClean` will be the same in both examples.

Now as pointed out by axiac, you have the same confusion in your `Clean()` function. It uses both a reference and a `return`, and while `$source` is a reference to `$_POST`, `$toClean` is not anymore. All variables you modify need to be references in order to have `$_POST` modified, if somehow there is a copy in an intermediary step, it will become modified itself, but not the original variable. Two solutions :

- use `$source` directly
- Assign `$source` to `$toClean` by reference. In this case you can't use the ternary form.  Try :

```php
if( !is_array($source) || empty($field) )
    $toClean = &$source;
else
    $toClean = &$source[$field];
```

Once you do something like this, you might want to have a look at [array_walk and array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to make the overall code simpler :

```php
class Input
{
    public function Clean(&$source, $field = null)
    {
        if( !is_array($source) || empty($field) )
            $toClean = &$source;
        else
            $toClean = &$source[$field];

        if (is_array($toClean)) {
            array_walk($toClean, array($this, 'DoClean');
        } else {
            $this->DoClean($toClean);
        }
    }

    private function DoClean(&$toClean)
    {
        $toClean = strip_tags(trim($toClean));
    }
}
(new Input())->Clean($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
class Input
{
    public function Clean(&$source, $field = null)
    {
        $toClean = is_array($source) ? empty($field) ? $source : $source[$field] : $source;


        //check if we are going to clean the whole array or only a specific field!
        if (is_array($toClean)) {
            //we foreach every key/field
            foreach ($toClean as $to => $value)
                $toClean[$to] = $this->DoClean($value);

            // CHANGE SOURCE ARRAY
            $source = $toClean;
        } else {
            $this->DoClean($toClean);
        }

        return $toClean;
    }

    private function DoClean(&$toClean)
    {
        return strip_tags(trim($toClean));

    }
}

(new Input())->Clean($_POST);
```

Error was - you copy of `source` array

Comment: @Cimbali How i understand this code, author want change every value that will be passed by reference in this function (like `shuffle` or `array_shift`  methods). I think `return` is not need for this method. But it author must decide. I just show the error location

Comment: @Cimbali but it is will be strange and not clear if method will modify arrays and don't modify string. I think method must work similar for every argument type. So, it must modify all arguments and return `bool` or return modified result.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `$_POST` by reference to the `Clean()` method but you don't change it in the method.

Work on `$source` (and drop `$toClean`) in function `Clean()` and it will change the values in `$_POST` (or whatever array you pass to `Clean()` as argument when you call it).